# Camel: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultEndpoint must be specified

Tags: java, apache-camel, illegalargumentexception

I am new to Apache Camel. I am trying to send headers along with request body to a route in Apache Camel.

```
// headers is a map
APIResponse response = (APIResponse) producer.requestBodyAndHeader("direct:route1",body,headers);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultEndpoint must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:308)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.getMandatoryDefaultEndpoint(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:462)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:289)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably confused the actual method to invoke. Instead of invoking [`template.requestBodyAndHeaders(String, Object, Map<String, Object>)`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html#requestBodyAndHeaders(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map)), which you actually intended to invoke, you most likely invoked [`template.requestBodyAndHeader(Object, String, Object)`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html#requestBodyAndHeader(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) in case your message body was actually of type `String`.

The latter case would only set one single header value with the key being the second input parameter and its value the 3rd parameter. Here also, as no endpoint information is given, it would fallback to the default endpoint which would explain the error you are seeing.

Comment: beware the plural vs. singular method names!

requestBodyAndHeaders vs. requestBodyAndHeader

We just spent 1h on the same issue because we are blind :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure off the top of my head why that's not working, it looks okay to me. As a test, you could try splitting out the endpoint and see if it works?

```
Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct:route1");
producer.setDefaultEndpoint(endpoint);
producer.requestBodyAndHeader(body,headers);
```

Another thing you could test is to try "seda" instead of "direct", as the "direct" endpoints can have issues if you are loading your components in a funny order (i.e. if the consumer is not intialized yet, the "direct" endpoint might not exist)

Comment: Thank you for responding, I tried it before posing the question and it did not help.